# DjangoRestFramework: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, backend

I traced this error and found that `serializer.data` is causing the problem. I have used similar code in my other Django apps and they are running perfectly fine.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Products(models.Model):
    Subcategory=models.ForeignKey(Subcategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Category,Subcategory,Products

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model='Category'
        fields='__all__'

class SubcategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model='Subcategory'
        fields='__all__'

class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model='Products'
        fields='__all__'
```

`views.py`

```
    def post(self,request):
        action=request.query_params['action']
        if action=='add':
            category_name=request.query_params['category_name']
            category=Category(name=category_name)
            category.save()
            serializer=CategorySerializer(Category.objects.filter(name=category),many=True)
            return JsonResponse({"category details":serializer.data})
```

I went through all the posts on StackOverflow based on this error but none of those could help me resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `model` field should refer to the model class, not a string (literal) with the name of the class, like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Category, Subcategory, Products

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class SubcategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subcategory
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = '__all__'
```

So here `model = Category`, *not* <s>`model = 'Category'`</s>. The same for the other serializers.

The logic in your `post` view is not entirely correct, you probably want to filter on `category_name`:

```
    def post(self,request):
        action=request.query_params['action']
        if action=='add':
            category_name=request.query_params['category_name']
            category=Category(name=category_name)
            category.save()
            serializer=CategorySerializer(Category.objects.filter(name=category_name),many=True)
            return JsonResponse({"category details":serializer.data})
```

> **Note**: models are usually given *singular* names, so `Product` instead of `Products`.